# Why does a hash of string produce different results in C# and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, hash, md5

I have this function in my C# code:

```cs
public static string ComputeHash(string input)
{
    string hash = string.Empty;
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5Hash = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        try
        {
            // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
            byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Loop through each byte of the hashed data and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                sb.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));

            hash = sb.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex);
        }

    return hash;
}
```

This is how I store my value in SQL Server:

```sql
lower(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', @partIdentifier), 2))
```

The result of the two values is completely different. Does anyone have an idea why? Or how could I solve it?

Comment: If `@partIdentifier` is `nvarchar`, then it's utf-16. If it's `varchar`, then it's whatever codepage is selected in your database. Neither of these cases is utf-8.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be the problem